# How to improve in-browser CSS/React development experience without rebuilding?

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

My team maintains an old coffeescript+knockout UI, of which we're slowly replacing pieces with modern React code. The project has a complicated build system, but we've been able to hook create-react-app into it and inject the bundled files into the main app. This works, but rebuilds are costly.

How can I improve our development experience by editing whatever we can inside the browser, rather than waiting for a full rebuild on each change?

In some cases we can just use the CRA dev server which is great, but we often rely on styling and code from the rest of the app so working on each component in complete isolation is difficult.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For CSS you can always use your browser's dev tools to change styles until it looks nice, then you copy from dev tools to your app and only have to rebuild once.

For JS you could use [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html) (HMR) as a webpack plugin (not included in CRA, you will have to [`eject`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup)).